# Why Logical And Replacing With Character In Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using javascript in wordpress but problem is that **#038;** is appending after every logical **&** operator,so that script is not working.

**Screen Shot:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DgY5.png)

**Original Code**

```
           if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {
                    document.cookie = 'testcookie';
                    cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
                }
```

Please help.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275282/prevent-escaping-javascript-in-visual-editor

Comment: As I can guess, you're using Visual Text Editor for inserting js. It's bad idea, but if you need it, then you just need to swith editor from `visual` to `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i check your code, Please mention the editor you are using along with your code. So that i can give you a positive result.